# Как сделать поиск по условию

Tags: php, laravel

> Мне нужно что бы выводились только те пользователи которые попадают в
>   условия .Например если да две даты с(01.01.2020) до(06.01.2020) и все
>   пользователи у которых дата находится в этом промежутке выводились на
>   экран

***контроллер***

```
$data_ot = $request->input('data_ot');
$data_do = $request->input('data_do');
$othet = Othet::where('data_start',$data_do,'=>',$data_ot)->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как то так

```
Othet::whereBetween('data_start', [$data_ot, $data_do])->get();
```

Не забудьте про правильный формат даты.